# How to Change Unity Toggle background image in Code C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have unity project and I used five toggle and set 1 image for the background another image to Checkmark.
I want to set that both images by using code(C#).

[image]

Comment: Hi. What have you tried. So is not a code writing service please show what you have done and explain what it does and what it should have done and provide [mcve]

Comment: I don't have any idea about that so I need step by step.

Comment: I have two conditions, so that If one condition true, set one image and otherwise set another image. that's why I need to set a image by c# coding.

Comment: you actually answered your own question. if (condition_1) { setimage1(); } else {setimage2();} ..

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Image myImageComponent;
public Sprite myImage; //Drag your first sprite here in inspector.

void Start() //Lets start by getting a reference to your image component.
{
    myImageComponent = GetComponent<Image>(); //Your image component is the one attached to this gameObject.
}

public void SetImage() //method to set our first image
{
    myImageComponent.sprite = myImage;
}
```

Comment: I need to clear about how to set Image for Toggle > background.. I Have WeeklyDayPanel > MonToggle >BackGround...(I already set image source in unity), I want to set that image by using code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for every ones to support me and I find a answer to this question. 
answer is:

first we need to declare varibles(for reference to Image) and then set images to variable from unity.

```
public Sprite MondayRW;
public Sprite MondayRG;
public Sprite TuesRW;
public Sprite TuesRG;
public Sprite WendRW;
public Sprite WendRG;
public Sprite ThurRW;

//If Phone language is Russian, Set Russian value images to tonggles.
        if(Application.systemLanguage == SystemLanguage.Russian)
        { 
            GameObject.Find("BackgroundMon").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = MondayRW;
            GameObject.Find("CheckmarkMon").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = MondayRG;
            GameObject.Find("BackgroundTue").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = TuesRW;
            GameObject.Find("CheckmarkTue").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = TuesRG;
            GameObject.Find("BackgroundWed").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = WendRW;
            GameObject.Find("CheckmarkWed").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = WendRG;
            GameObject.Find("BackgroundThu").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = ThurRW;

        }
```

I find the place to replace my image from `GameObject.Find("BackgroundMon")` and then I set my image to that place.